# Past Simple or Past Perfect with "before"

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

When we use or have the word **"before"** in our sentence, can we use Past Simple instead or Past Perfect?

- Yesterday I went to Michael's but before that I (had) visited Jenny.
- Yesterday I (had) visited Jenny before I went to Michael's.

Comment: The guiding principle FumbleFingers has provided is that *don't use past perfect unless you really have to*. So perfect tense is not required since it's clear which action had taken place before another.

Comment: I've upvoted user178049's answer (and by default, FumbleFingers's principle), but personally, I do like to (over)use past perfect to make things more clear (it just sounds better in my head). This being said, the above is clear-enough with just past simple.

Comment: And as an aside, I probably would have said, "Michael's." I assume you mean "went over to Michael's house" by your use of "went to Michael"?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Maybe, let's change it to that. However, that doesn't really matter.

Comment: It doesn't :O :D? Or you mean it doesn't matter for this example?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang The latter. I wasn't thinking of whether it should be Michael's place or house or whatever, or Michael himself.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I wouldn't overuse perfect tenses without some reason in context. It sounds good, but understanding requires taking in additional information that may not be specified.

Comment: Once you put in the "had", I am expecting additional information regarding something else that happened.

Comment: Hmmm, I see what user3169 is saying and I could understand that in a sentence without context, but in the example given, there had been context, so I would not be "expecting additional information" as I would feel like it had already been given. @user3169, had you meant specifically for the OP's example that you would have been expecting additional information? And if so, may I ask for an example within the context of the OP's example?

Comment: Also, just re-reading the examples now, I would feel like the second one would require both to be past perfect if the first one is, i.e., if we want to say, "Yesterday I had visited Jenny"... I feel like we would need to say, "...before I had gone to Michael's." Perhaps not "need to say," but I feel like the whole thing would sound more smooth.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Why do you think so?